# creating a new list isn't working with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create a new list using the df = coffee and wanted to call in the column Type, which has 4 (Coffee, Expresso, Herbal Tea, and Tea) into a separate list. One for bean and the other leaf. It runs but doesn't print the list I am looking for and I want to imply .lower to lower the first capital in each one.

thanks

```
bean = []
for b in df['Type']:
    #for y in df['Type'] == 'Coffee' and df['Type'] == 'Expresso':
    if b == 'Coffee'.lower():
        bean.append(b)
    elif b == 'Expresso'.lower():
        bean.append(b)
print(bean)

leaf = []
for l in df['Type']:
    if l == 'Tea'.lower():
    #x in df['Type'] == 'Tea' and df['Type'] == 'Herbal Tea':
        leaf.append(l)
    elif l == 'Herbal Tea'.lower():
        leaf.append(l)
print(leaf)
```

Comment: The code works and prints the expected Lists (unless there something wrong in your DataFrame). The commented out expressions are not correct syntax.